# Change .html to .php

Tags: php, .htaccess

How can I convert the html extension into php using php script?

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your .htaccess file in Apache:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

and all files with HTML extension will be parsed as PHP

Answer (score 2):

> Hi! how can i convert the html
>   extension into php Hi! how can i convert the html extension into php **>>using php script<<**.

Check out the php's [`rename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) function.

> rename — Renames a file or directory

**Example:**

```
rename('your_file.html', 'your_file.php') or die('Could not rename the file.');
```